# How to use mvc validation in angularjs? And is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have form in mvc and for example my route is : www.example.com/personalInfo but when i hit submit button it redirects me to www.example.com/app/personalInformation ... so my question is how can i use mvc validation in angularjs and is it possible.I am using ui.router for routing....This is how i use my form in mvc:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("PersonalInformation", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editUserForm", @class = "form" }))
    {

    }



<input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn-block secondary-button save-changes" onclick="SavePersonalInformation()"  value="@Translator.Translate("SAVE_CHANGES")">
```

Comment: Do you want to do client side or server side validation? MVC doesn't validate on client side. It could only add some rules for example "Required" and "MaxLength" to form fields. But nothing changed on server side - you still can use ModelState.IsValid. To do client side validation you have to use JavaScript either AngularJS itself or JQuery.